# how to create a separate login page for easyadmin and client page in symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

I have installed FOSUser bundle and Easyadmin in Symfony 3. Everything works fine.

FYI, my route for easyadmin is `/admin` .

If the user is not logged in and will access the `/admin` route, it will be redirected to `/login` which is the FOSUser bundle configured.

What I want is to have a separate page for admin login and client login.

Suppose, if the user (not logged) will access `/admin` it should be redirected to admin login which is `/admin/login`. And if the user will access the `/dashboard` of client, it should be redirected to `/login`.

Below is my security.yml configuration:

```
#From security.yml file

  firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
            # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider                
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            always_use_default_target_path: false
            default_target_path: /dashboard
```

Below is my routing.yml configuration:

```
 #routing.yml
 easy_admin_bundle:
     resource: "@EasyAdminBundle/Controller/"
     type:     annotation
     prefix:   /admin
```

Does anybody know?

Comment: if you add some permissions to your users table then you can do it with one login page, let PHP figure out if it is a user or admin

Comment: I am using the fosUser bundle. It redirects automatically to `/login` if i tried to access the `/admin` . Do you have some tutorials about this? thanks

Comment: I don't know the fosUser bundle. But what I'm saying is, you only need `/login` if you check for the users permissions. Otherwise there will probably be a way but not one I can help you with, sorry.

Comment: Got solved my problem. For future reference, see my answer below. thanks

Answer (score 2):

After changing my settings, I got fixed my problem.

I added `prefix:/admin` under fos_user on my routing. Meaning, the login will be redirected to `/admin` but then, since the user is not yet logged in, it will push back to `/admin/login` uri.

```
# app/config/routing.yml
fos_user:
   prefix:   /admin
   resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

#Easy admin bundle
easy_admin_bundle:
   resource: "@EasyAdminBundle/Controller/"
   type:     annotation
   prefix:   /admin
```

Also, here is the configuration on my security.yml. Make sure that the provider is `fos_userbundle`.

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

firewalls:            
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    admin_area:
        pattern:    ^/admin
        anonymous:  ~
        provider:   fos_userbundle
        form_login:
            default_target_path: /admin
            check_path: /admin/login_check
            login_path: /admin/login
            remember_me: true
        logout:
            path:   /admin/logout
            target: /admin
    main:
        anonymous: ~
```